# Pandas DataFrame - разбить строки на n окон, сдвинуть окна на m элементов, найти среднее

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть DataFrame, в столбце содержится (для примера) 30 строк, необходимо разбить их на окна размером 5 элементов, сдвинуть каждое окно на 4 элемента относительно другого окна и найти среднее значение по строке.
Должно остаться 10 строк.
Количество строк и размер окна может быть произвольным.
Есть ли какой-то механизм смещения окон и вычисления значений в pandas?

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну как-то так. Просто всё это надо тщательно продумать и посчитать, а так ничего сложного:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'feature': [i + j + i / 10 for i in range(6) for j in range(1, 6)]})
df_new = pd.DataFrame([[df.iloc[j + i * 4, 0] if i - 1 < j < i + 5 else pd.NA for i in range(6)] for j in range(10)])
new_feature_mean = df_new.sum(axis=1) / (~df_new.isna()).sum(axis=1)
```

Что получается в `new_feature_mean`:

```
0     1.00
1     2.05
2     3.10
3     4.15
4     5.20
5     6.30
6     7.35
7     8.40
8     9.45
9    10.50
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @Kir Отметьте мой ответ как полезный/правильный тогда )

Comment: Увы, пока не хватает балов, но как только, как сразу)

Comment: @Kir, для того чтобы [принять ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) балы не нужны - они нужны только для [голосования](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) ;)

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо! разобрался)